# SSTP: Certificate issue

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, sstp

So I'm building an SSTP VPN.

I get the following error when trying to connect to the VPN:

`A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.`

To generate the certificate I used `selfssl.exe` from the IIS 6 toolkit, with the identical CN as the DNS name I'm connecting to.

This was done ON the VPN server. Then I went to the Personal Certificate store and exported that certificate to the desktop. I did not export the Private Keys.

In RRAS itself I configured the VPN to use this certificate, and did the same in NPS with PEAP to use that certificate.

Then on the client I made sure that the exported certificate is installed under the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`, on the Local Machine (not user!).

Now according to the internet (and the noumerous questions and answers I find on this site) this should be sufficiaent. However I still hit the error.

What could I do, or do you have additional pointers for me to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is embarrassing.

The certificate offered on port 443 was indeed not matching, because somebody (i.e. the network admin) mapped port 443 to 3389, which gave the certificate for remote desktop, not the one I configured on SSTP.

Found that out with a certificate checker.